# Почему после нажатия BitBtn эта кнопка выделяется

Tags: delphi

Есть ли какое-нибудь свойство, которое отвечает за выделение кнопки BitBtn после нажатия. На скрине пример выделения после нажатия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по скришотам, вы находитесь в редакторе форм Delphi. Запустите само приложение, в нем такого не будет.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Будет все то же самое